# using swift extension from objc, and type difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm getting the following error on simulator iphone6 and above.

> Multiple methods named 'intValue' found with mismatched result,
>   parameter type or attributes

on simulator 5 and below, there's no error.

Offending code is

```
int destinationType = [[args objectForKey:@"destinationType"] intValue];
```

I suspect it's due to the swift extension I added

```
 extension NSNull {

     func intValue() -> Int {
         return 0
     }
 }
```

So should I be worried about that the code won't compile on simulator 6 and above?

** EDIT **

It seems the difference is coming from the fact that iPhone 5 and less are 32bit and iPhone5s and above are 64bit.

So I should return more precise type than Int which can be either int32 or int64.

Now my code reads as following and wonder if its the right solution

```
     func intValue() -> Int32 {
         return 0
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objective-C method is expecting a C `int`. But a Swift Int is *not* a C `int`. Thus, specifying Int32 is right, because that *is* the same as `int`, and also because it is what other implementations of `intValue` return.

Of course, this brings up the fact that the method name `intValue` is already in use within Objective-C. Objective-C has no overloading, so if you are going to pick this name, you *must* match the existing signature (as you are now doing).